Combinatorics: How to use the tree dissymmetry theorem to find singularities?

Denote by $T(z)$ the exponential generating function of the class $\mathcal{T}$ of
labelled (unrooted) trees in which all vertices have degree $1$ or $3$. Use the tree dissymmetry theorem (see below) to derive an expression of $T(z)$ in terms of $\left(\mathcal{T}^{\bullet -\bullet}\right)(z)$. Determine the dominant singularities of $\left(\mathcal{T}^{\bullet -\bullet}\right)(z)$ and singular expansions near those singularities.

I can see that

$\mathcal{T}^{\bullet -\bullet} \simeq \text{SET}_2(\mathcal{T}^{\bullet})$: For any given tree $T \in \mathcal{T}^{\bullet -\bullet}$ we delete the marked edge and thus split the tree in two separate tree. We then mark the edges of the edge we deleted previously.
$\mathcal{T}^{\bullet \rightarrow \bullet} \simeq \mathcal{T}^{\bullet - \bullet} + \mathcal{T}^{\bullet - \bullet}$: For any given tree $T_1 \in \mathcal{T}^{\bullet \rightarrow \bullet}$ we can map $T$ to its undirected version $T^\prime \in \mathcal{T}^{\bullet - \bullet}$. However, we note that under this map the tree $T_2 \in \mathcal{T}^{\bullet \rightarrow \bullet}$, which differes from $T_1$ only in orientation of  the marked edge, also maps to $T^\prime$.

So using the tree dissymmetry theorem we get:
\begin{align}
T(z) &= T^{\bullet}(z) + T^{\bullet - \bullet}(z)- T^{\bullet \rightarrow \bullet}(z)
 \\
&= T^{\bullet}(z) - T^{\bullet - \bullet}(z) \\
\end{align}
So, $T^{\bullet - \bullet}(z) = T^{\bullet}(z) - T(z) = n^{n-1} - n^{n-2} = n^{n-2}(n-1)$.
However, there seems to be a mistake here, as there are no singularities in $T^{\bullet - \bullet}(z)$. Could you please tell me what I am doing wrong?

Tree Dissymmetry Theorem: Let

$\mathcal{T}$ denote the class of all trees
$\mathcal{T}^{\bullet}$ denote the class of all trees where one vertex is marked
$\mathcal{T}^{\bullet -\bullet}$ denote the class of all trees where one edge is marked
$\mathcal{T}^{\bullet \rightarrow \bullet}$ denote the class of all trees where one edge with orientation is marked

Then $\mathcal{T} + \mathcal{T}^{\bullet \rightarrow \bullet} \simeq \mathcal{T}^{\bullet} + \mathcal{T}^{\bullet - \bullet}$.


For labelled trees OEIS A274056 may be of some use, as well as MSE 18186933.
